# JqGrid - Header color change for Frozen columns only

Tags: jqgrid

Can we change the Background color and font color of only the frozen columns header.
I tried this by changing the following in ui.jqgrid.css.

```
.ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-hdiv {position: relative; margin: 0;padding: 0; overflow-x: hidden; border-left: 0 none !important; border-top : 0 none !important; border-right : 0 none !important;background-color:#f0dcdd !important;color:Black;}
```

This has not changed the color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CSS rile like the following

```css
.ui-jqgrid .frozen-div .ui-th-column { background: #f0dcdd; color: black; }
```

see [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/colorOfFrozenHeaders.htm) which displays the result like on the picture below

[image]