# How to keep grid width if colums are switched in column menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

jqgrid has fixed width.

I tried code below based on [How to change column name in column chooser pop up in jqgrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29365758/how-to-change-column-name-in-column-chooser-pop-up-in-jqgrid)

to create column switcher.
After turning some column on or off grid width changes to full screen.
How to fix this so that grid keeps its width after column seelcton in column menu ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>https://stackoverflow.com/q/27617764/315935</title>
    <meta name="author" content="Oleg Kiriljuk">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/free-jqgrid/4.8.0/css/ui.jqgrid.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/free-jqgrid/4.8.0/plugins/ui.multiselect.css">
    <style>
        html, body { font-size: 75%; }
        .ui-datepicker select.ui-datepicker-year,
        .ui-datepicker select.ui-datepicker-month {
            color: black
        }
        .ui-jqgrid .ui-pg-table .ui-pg-button.ui-state-active { margin: 1px; font-weight: normal; }
    </style>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/free-jqgrid/4.8.0/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
    <script>
        $.jgrid = $.jgrid || {};
        $.jgrid.no_legacy_api = true;
        $.jgrid.useJSON = true;
    </script>
    <!--<script src="../jqGrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.src.js"></script>-->
    <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/free-jqgrid/4.8.0/js/jquery.jqgrid.src.js"></script>
  <script src="http://rawgit.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/master/plugins/jquery.jqgrid.showhidecolumnmenu.js"></script>
    <script src="http://rawgit.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/master/plugins/jquery.contextmenu-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="http://rawgit.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/master/plugins/jquery.createcontexmenufromnavigatorbuttons.js"></script>

    <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/free-jqgrid/4.8.0/plugins/ui.multiselect.js"></script>
    <script>
    //<![CDATA[
    /*global $ */
    /*jslint browser: true */
    $(function () {
        "use strict";
        var mydata = [
                { id: "10",  invdate: "2007-10-01", name: "test",   note: "note",   amount: "", tax: "", closed: true,  ship_via: "TN", total: "" },
                { id: "20",  invdate: "2007-10-02", name: "test2",  note: "note2",  amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.00" },
                { id: "30",  invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3",  note: "note3",  amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "430.00" },
                { id: "40",  invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test4",  note: "note4",  amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", closed: true,  ship_via: "TN", total: "210.00" },
                { id: "50",  invdate: "2007-10-31", name: "test5",  note: "note5",  amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.00" },
                { id: "60",  invdate: "2007-09-06", name: "test6",  note: "note6",  amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "430.00" },
                { id: "70",  invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test7",  note: "note7",  amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", closed: true,  ship_via: "TN", total: "210.00" },
                { id: "80",  invdate: "2007-10-03", name: "test8",  note: "note8",  amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.00" },
                { id: "90",  invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test9",  note: "note9",  amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "TN", total: "430.00" },
                { id: "100", invdate: "2007-09-08", name: "test10", note: "note10", amount: "500.00", tax: "30.00", closed: true,  ship_via: "TN", total: "530.00" },
                { id: "110", invdate: "2007-09-08", name: "test11", note: "note11", amount: "500.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "530.00" },
                { id: "120", invdate: "2007-09-10", name: "test12", note: "note12", amount: "500.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "530.00" }
            ],
            $grid = $("#grid"),
            initDateEdit = function (elem) {
                $(elem).datepicker({
                    dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
                    autoSize: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    changeMonth: true,
                    showButtonPanel: true,
                    showWeek: true
                });
            },
            initDateSearch = function (elem) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    initDateEdit(elem);
                }, 100);
            };

        $grid.jqGrid({
            data: mydata,
            colNames: ["", "Client", "Date", "Amount", "Tax", "Total", "Closed", "Shipped via", "Notes"],
            colModel: [
                { name: "act", template: "actions" },
                { name: "name", align: "center", width: 92, editrules: {required: true} },
                { name: "invdate", width: 72, align: "center", sorttype: "date", frozen: true,
                    formatter: "date", formatoptions: { newformat: "d-M-Y", reformatAfterEdit: true }, datefmt: "d-M-Y",
                    editoptions: { dataInit: initDateEdit },
                    searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne", "lt", "le", "gt", "ge"], dataInit: initDateSearch } },
                { name: "amount", width: 56, template: "number", hidden: true },
                { name: "tax", width: 35, template: "number", autoResizableMinColSize: 40, hidden: true },
                { name: "total", width: 43, template: "number", hidden: true },
                { name: "closed", width: 49, template: "booleanCheckboxFa" },
                { name: "ship_via", width: 76, align: "center", formatter: "select",
                    edittype: "select", editoptions: { value: "FE:FedEx;TN:TNT;IN:Intim", defaultValue: "IN" },
                    stype: "select", searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne"], value: ":Any;FE:FedEx;TN:TNT;IN:IN" } },
                { name: "note", width: 3343, edittype: "textarea", sortable: false }
            ],
            cmTemplate: { editable: true, autoResizable: true },
            iconSet: "fontAwesome",
            rowNum: 10,
            autoResizing: { compact: true },
            rowList: [5, 10, 20, "10000:All"],
            //pagerpos: "right",
            //viewrecords: true,
            //pgbuttons: false,
            //pginput: false,
            //width: 390,
            toppager: true,
            rownumbers: true,
            sortname: "invdate",
            sortorder: "desc",
            navOptions: {
                position: "center",
                addtext: "Add",
                edittext: "Edit",
                deltext: "Delete",
                searchtext: "Search",
                refreshtext: "Reload",
                viewtext: "View",
                savetext: "Save",
                canceltext: "Cancel",
                iconsOverText: true
            },
            caption: "Demonstration how to make full width navigator bar",
width: '100px',  
      }).jqGrid("navGrid", {view: true})
        .jqGrid("inlineNav")
        //.jqGrid("filterToolbar")
//        .jqGrid("gridResize")
.jqGrid("showHideColumnMenu")
         .jqGrid("createContexMenuFromNavigatorButtons", $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "pager"));

        $grid.jqGrid('setGridWidth', 200, false);

        var autoedit = true;
        $grid.jqGrid("navButtonAdd", "#grid_toppager", {
            buttonicon: "fa-star",
            caption: "Toggle",
            id: "AutoEdit",
            title: "Toggle autoedit",
            onClickButton: function (options, e) {
                var $me = $(e.currentTarget);
                $me.toggleClass("ui-state-active");
                autoedit = $me.hasClass("ui-state-active");
                $me.attr("aria-pressed", autoedit ? "true" : "false");
            }
        });
        $("#grid_toppager")
            .find(".ui-pg-button")
            .each(function (i) {
                $(this).attr({
                    tabindex: String(i),
                    role: "button"
                });
            });
        //$("#AutoEdit").attr("role", "button");
        if (autoedit) {
            $("#AutoEdit").click();
        }
        $grid.jqGrid("navButtonAdd", "#grid_toppager", {
            buttonicon: "fa-table",
            caption: "Columns",
            title: "Choose columns",
            onClickButton: function (options, e) {
                $(this).jqGrid("columnChooser");
            }
        });
        $("#grid_toppager_left").hide();
        $("#grid_toppager_right").hide();
        $("#grid_toppager_center").attr("colspan", "2");
        $("#grid_toppager_center").css({width: "", "text-align": "left", "white-space": ""});
        $("#grid_toppager_center").find(">.navtable").append(
            $("#grid_toppager_center").find(">table.ui-pg-table")
        );
        $("#grid_toppager_center").find(">.navtable").children().each(function() {
            $(this).css("float", "left");
        });
        $grid.bind("jqGridAfterGridComplete", function () {
            var p = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam"), $toppager = $(p.toppager);
            $toppager.find(".navtable").css("width", "");
        });
    });
    //]]>
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="outerDiv" style="margin:5px;">
        <table id="grid"></table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Free jqGrid 4.8 are based of the jqGrid 4.7 version. If you examine [the lines of code](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/v4.7.0/js/grid.base.js#L3525-L3526) you will see that the described behavior is the standard behavior in case of usage default `shrinkToFit: true` option. So you will have the same behavior in `columnChooser` for example if you would use default `shrinkToFit: true` option.

Write me if the usage of `shrinkToFit: false` option can't be used in your environment.

Comment: @Andrus: You are welcome! It's just a workaround. I will try to allow to fix the problem in another way in the future.