# How to stop free jqgrid disabled toolbar buttons to respond to mouse clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

Free jqgrid toolbar disabled buttons generate click events on mouse clicks. In causes invalid code execution.
To reproduce, open page belwo in Chrome, and click in disabled inline edit or pager button.
Rectangel appears and remains around button. Click method code is executed.

I fixed this by adding check

```
    if (p.savedRow === undefined || p.savedRow.length === 0)
        return;
```

to jqgrid source code :

```
    if (o.save) {
        $self.jqGrid("navButtonAdd", elem, {
            caption: o.savetext || "",
            title: o.savetitle || "Save row",
            commonIconClass: o.commonIconClass,
            buttonicon: o.saveicon,
            iconsOverText: o.iconsOverText,
            id: gid + "_ilsave",
            onClickButton: function () {
                 // PATCH if removed clicking in disabled save button causes exception
                if (p.savedRow === undefined || p.savedRow.length === 0) {
                    return;
                        }
                        // END
```

But jqgrid should not fire thois method.

How to fix this ?

Code to reproduce:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>http://stackoverflow.com/q/27617764/315935</title>
    <meta name="author" content="Oleg Kiriljuk">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/free-jqgrid/4.8.0/css/ui.jqgrid.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/free-jqgrid/4.8.0/plugins/ui.multiselect.css">
    <style>
        html, body { font-size: 75%; }
        .ui-datepicker select.ui-datepicker-year,
        .ui-datepicker select.ui-datepicker-month {
            color: black
        }
        .ui-jqgrid .ui-pg-table .ui-pg-button.ui-state-active { margin: 1px; font-weight: normal; }






.ui-jqgrid > .ui-jqgrid-pager .navtable,
.ui-jqgrid > .ui-jqgrid-view > .ui-jqgrid-toppager .navtable {
    font-size: 16px;
}

.ui-jqgrid .ui-pg-table {
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}

    .ui-pg-table .ui-pg-button:hover, .ui-jqgrid .ui-pg-table.navtable .ui-pg-button.ui-state-active {
        font-weight: normal;
        border: 0 none;
        background: #b6dbf7 url("images/ui-bg_glass_75_d0e5f5_1x400.png") 50% 50% repeat-x;
    }

.ui-pg-table .ui-pg-table .ui-pg-button:hover {
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 3px;
}

.ui-jqgrid .ui-pg-table.navtable .ui-pg-button:hover {
    font-weight: normal;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 2px;
}

.ui-jqgrid .jqgrow .ui-jqgrid-actions > .ui-pg-div:hover {
    margin: 0 1px;
    border: 0 none;
    background: #b6dbf7 url("images/ui-bg_glass_75_d0e5f5_1x400.png") 50% 50% repeat-x;
}




    </style>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/free-jqgrid/4.8.0/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js"></script>
    <script>
        $.jgrid = $.jgrid || {};
        $.jgrid.no_legacy_api = true;
        $.jgrid.useJSON = true;
    </script>
    <!--<script src="../jqGrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.src.js"></script>-->
    <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/free-jqgrid/4.8.0/js/jquery.jqgrid.src.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/free-jqgrid/4.8.0/plugins/ui.multiselect.js"></script>
    <script>
    //<![CDATA[
    /*global $ */
    /*jslint browser: true */
    $(function () {
        "use strict";
        var mydata = [
                { id: "10",  invdate: "2007-10-01", name: "test",   note: "note",   amount: "", tax: "", closed: true,  ship_via: "TN", total: "" },
                { id: "20",  invdate: "2007-10-02", name: "test2",  note: "note2",  amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.00" },
                { id: "30",  invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test3",  note: "note3",  amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "430.00" },
                { id: "40",  invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test4",  note: "note4",  amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", closed: true,  ship_via: "TN", total: "210.00" },
                { id: "50",  invdate: "2007-10-31", name: "test5",  note: "note5",  amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.00" },
                { id: "60",  invdate: "2007-09-06", name: "test6",  note: "note6",  amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "430.00" },
                { id: "70",  invdate: "2007-10-04", name: "test7",  note: "note7",  amount: "200.00", tax: "10.00", closed: true,  ship_via: "TN", total: "210.00" },
                { id: "80",  invdate: "2007-10-03", name: "test8",  note: "note8",  amount: "300.00", tax: "20.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "320.00" },
                { id: "90",  invdate: "2007-09-01", name: "test9",  note: "note9",  amount: "400.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "TN", total: "430.00" },
                { id: "100", invdate: "2007-09-08", name: "test10", note: "note10", amount: "500.00", tax: "30.00", closed: true,  ship_via: "TN", total: "530.00" },
                { id: "110", invdate: "2007-09-08", name: "test11", note: "note11", amount: "500.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "530.00" },
                { id: "120", invdate: "2007-09-10", name: "test12", note: "note12", amount: "500.00", tax: "30.00", closed: false, ship_via: "FE", total: "530.00" }
            ],
            $grid = $("#grid"),
            initDateEdit = function (elem) {
                $(elem).datepicker({
                    dateFormat: "dd-M-yy",
                    autoSize: true,
                    changeYear: true,
                    changeMonth: true,
                    showButtonPanel: true,
                    showWeek: true
                });
            },
            initDateSearch = function (elem) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    initDateEdit(elem);
                }, 100);
            };

        $grid.jqGrid({
            data: mydata,
            colNames: ["", "Client", "Date", "Amount", "Tax", "Total", "Closed", "Shipped via", "Notes"],
            colModel: [
                { name: "act", template: "actions" },
                { name: "name", align: "center", width: 192, editrules: {required: true} },
                { name: "invdate", width: 172, align: "center", sorttype: "date", frozen: true,
                    formatter: "date", formatoptions: { newformat: "d-M-Y", reformatAfterEdit: true }, datefmt: "d-M-Y",
                    editoptions: { dataInit: initDateEdit },
                    searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne", "lt", "le", "gt", "ge"], dataInit: initDateSearch } },
                { name: "amount", width: 556, template: "number", hidden: true },
                { name: "tax", width: 535, template: "number", autoResizableMinColSize: 40, hidden: true },
                { name: "total", width: 543, template: "number", hidden: true },
                { name: "closed", width: 549, template: "booleanCheckboxFa" },
                { name: "ship_via", width: 976, align: "center", formatter: "select",
                    edittype: "select", editoptions: { value: "FE:FedEx;TN:TNT;IN:Intim", defaultValue: "IN" },
                    stype: "select", searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "ne"], value: ":Any;FE:FedEx;TN:TNT;IN:IN" } },
                { name: "note", width: 943, edittype: "textarea", sortable: false }
            ],

            cmTemplate: { editable: true, autoResizable: true },
            iconSet: "fontAwesome",
            rowNum: 10,
//            autoResizing: { compact: true },
            rowList: [5, 10, 20, "10000:All"],
            //pagerpos: "right",
            //viewrecords: true,
            //pgbuttons: false,
            //pginput: false,
            //width: 390,
            toppager: true,
            rownumbers: true,
            sortname: "invdate",
            sortorder: "desc",
            navOptions: {
                position: "center",
                addtext: "Add",
                edittext: "Edit",
                deltext: "Delete",
                searchtext: "Search",
                refreshtext: "Reload",
                viewtext: "View",
                savetext: "Save",
                canceltext: "Cancel",
                iconsOverText: true
            },
            caption: "Demonstration how to make full width navigator bar"
        }).jqGrid("navGrid", {view: true})
        .jqGrid("inlineNav")
        //.jqGrid("filterToolbar")
//        .jqGrid("gridResize")
;

        var autoedit = true;
        $grid.jqGrid("navButtonAdd", "#grid_toppager", {
            buttonicon: "fa-star",
            caption: "Toggle",
            id: "AutoEdit",
            title: "Toggle autoedit",
            onClickButton: function (options, e) {
                var $me = $(e.currentTarget);
                $me.toggleClass("ui-state-active");
                autoedit = $me.hasClass("ui-state-active");
                $me.attr("aria-pressed", autoedit ? "true" : "false");
            }
        });
        $("#grid_toppager")
            .find(".ui-pg-button")
            .each(function (i) {
                $(this).attr({
                    tabindex: String(i),
                    role: "button"
                });
            });
        //$("#AutoEdit").attr("role", "button");
        if (autoedit) {
            $("#AutoEdit").click();
        }

        $("#grid_toppager_left").hide();
        $("#grid_toppager_right").hide();
        $("#grid_toppager_center").attr("colspan", "2");
        $("#grid_toppager_center").css({width: "", "text-align": "left", "white-space": ""});
        $("#grid_toppager_center").find(">.navtable").append(
            $("#grid_toppager_center").find(">table.ui-pg-table")
        );
        $("#grid_toppager_center").find(">.navtable").children().each(function() {
            $(this).css("float", "left");
        });
        $grid.bind("jqGridAfterGridComplete", function () {
            var p = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam"), $toppager = $(p.toppager);
            $toppager.find(".navtable").css("width", "");
        });
    });
    //]]>
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="outerDiv" style="width: 100%; height: 100%">
        <table id="grid" style="width: 100%; height: 100%"></table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the bug report! By the way the problem should exist already in old version of jqGrid.

I fixed the code. Now free jqGrid uses class

```css
.ui-jqgrid-disablePointerEvents {
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

(defined in `ui.jqgrid.css`) additionally to prevent unneeded mouse events on disabled elements. Moreover I included additional tests for old IE browsers which not yet supports `pointer-events: none`.

You should reload the latest source of free jqGrid from [GitHub](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid).