# Mass edit performance in free-jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

Need help in latest version of free-jqgrid when I do mass edit (inline edit of 100 rows at one time). It was really fast in JQGrid 4.3.1 After upgrading to free-jqgrid 4.13.6, I see it is very slow. I crated a similar example. This standalone example is not bad in performance. But I am not sure why it is taking long time to do inline edit in my application. Any hints would be a great help. 
In this example, check the multiselect check box (at the top left corner of the grid) and then click the button (at the top). Basically trying to understand when doing inline edit what all factors are taken into consideration.

Note: Just now realized that the single row inline edit also takes 2-3 seconds. which was really fast in 4.3.1.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>http://stackoverflow.com/q/27617764/315935</title>
    <meta name="author" content="Oleg Kiriljuk">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="jqGrid/css/ui.jqgrid.css">-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://rawgit.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/master/css/ui.jqgrid.css">
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body { font-size: 75%; }
    </style>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.jgrid = $.jgrid || {};
        $.jgrid.no_legacy_api = true;
        $.jgrid.useJSON = true;
    </script>
    <script src="http://rawgit.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/master/js/jquery.jqgrid.src.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="jqGrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.src.js"></script>-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        /*global $ */
        /*jslint eqeq: true, browser: true, plusplus: true */
        $(function () {
            "use strict";
            var $grid = $("#list"),
                gridData,
                startTime,
                measureTime = false,
                timeInterval;

            var date = new Date(), t = Object.prototype.toString.call(date), t1 = String(date);

            //alert("start to generate the data");
           // gridData = getGridData(100);
       // console.log(gridData);
            //alert("start to fill the grid")
            startTime = new Date();
            $grid.jqGrid({
                datatype: 'json',
        url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/efhbt',
        mtype: 'GET',
                colNames: ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee', 'ff', 'gg', 'hh', 'ii', 'jj', 'kk', 'll', 'mm'],
        colModel: [
                    { name: "aa", label: "c01" },
                    { name: "bb", label: "c02" },
                    { name: "cc", label: "c03" },
                    { name: "dd", label: "c04" },
                    { name: "ee", label: "c05" },
                    { name: "ff", label: "c06" },
                    { name: "gg", label: "c07", editable: true, stype: 'select', formatter: 'select',
            edittype: 'select', editoptions: {
                value: 'Select:Select;Y:Yes;N:No',
                multiple: false
            }
            },
                    { name: "hh", label: "c08", editable: true, stype: 'select', formatter: 'select',
            edittype: 'select', editoptions: {
                value: 'Select:Select;Y:Yes;N:No',
                multiple: false
            }
            },
                    { name: "ii", label: "c09", editable: true, stype: 'select', formatter: 'select',
            edittype: 'select', editoptions: {
                value: 'Select:Select;Y:Yes;N:No',
                multiple: false
            }
            },
                    { name: "jj", label: "c10", editable: true },
                    { name: "kk", label: "c11", editable: true },
                    { name: "ll", label: "c12", editable: true },
                    { name: "mm", label: "c13", editable: true }
                ],
                cmTemplate: { width: 100, autoResizable: true },
                rowNum: 1000,
        records: 1000,
                rownumWidth: 40,
                rowList: [20, 100, 1000, 10000, "100000:All"],
                viewrecords: true,
                rownumbers: true,
                toppager: false,
                pager: false,
                shrinkToFit: false,
        multiselect: true,
        editurl: 'clientArray',
        loadonce: true,
                onSortCol: function () {
                    startTime = new Date();
                    measureTime = true;
                },
        /*onSelectRow: function (rowid) {
                    var $self = $(this),
                        savedRow = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam", "savedRow");
                    if (savedRow.length > 0) {
                        $self.jqGrid("restoreRow", savedRow[0].id);
                    }
                    $self.jqGrid("editRow", rowid);
                },*/
                loadComplete: function () {
                    if (measureTime) {
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            alert("Total loading time: " + timeInterval + "ms");
                        }, 50);
                        measureTime = false;
                    }
                },
                autoencode: true,
                caption: "Shows the performance of resizing. Make double-click on the column resizer"
             }).jqGrid("filterToolbar", {
                    beforeSearch: function () {
                        startTime = new Date();
                        measureTime = true;
                        return false; // allow filtering
                    }
             }).jqGrid("gridResize");

             timeInterval = new Date() - startTime;
             setTimeout(function () {
                // alert("Total time: " + timeInterval + "ms");
             }, 50);




         // On Click Of Button
         $( "#Change_Value" ).click(function() {
        var v = $("#name").val();
        var myGrid = $("#list");
        var selRowIds = myGrid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "selarrrow");
        //alert(selRowId.length);
        for (var i = 0; i < selRowIds.length; i++) {
            //rowData = myGrid.jqGrid("getLocalRow", selRowIds[i]);
            // one can uses the data here
            myGrid.jqGrid("editRow", selRowIds[i], true);
        }
        });


        });
    //]]>
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
    <input type="button" name="Change_Value" id="Change_Value" value="Change Value" /> 
    </div>
    <div>
    <table id="list"></table>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "mass editing" (inline edit of 100 rows at one time) is bad in general because it produces a lot of changes on the page and **every change of one element follow web browser [reflow](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/reflow) for all existing elements**. Moreover displaying of the grid with 100 rows, where only about 25 are visible for the user (because of natural restriction of the monitor), reduce the performance additionally.

Compare the performance of [the initial demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/perTest.html) with [another one](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/perTest1.html), where I just included call of `jQuery.hide` before "mass editing" and `jQuery.show` after "mass editing":

```
myGrid.hide(); // !!! new line
for (var i = 0; i < selRowIds.length; i++) {
    myGrid.jqGrid("editRow", selRowIds[i], true);
}
myGrid.show(); // !!! new line
```

If you would use local paging with 25 rows, like on [the next demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/perTest2.html) you will increase the performance of the page additionally. Start of editing of 100 rows on initial demo takes on in my test about 1065 ms, the demo with editing of previously hiding grid takes 330 ms and the editing of 25 rows (local paging) takes 90 ms.

**UPDATE:** If you use frozen columns in the grid then you should destroy frozen columns by call of `destroyFrozenColumns` before the loop, where you call `editRow`, and then recreate the frozen columns by new call of `setFrozenColumns`. It should improve the performance additionally.

Comment: I completely understand that showing 100 rows is a really BAD idea. In my case there are about 5000 rows in search result. Si as per clients requirement we have to show 100 rows. Now my concern is, after upgrading to 4.13, the performance is too slow. So trying to understand what I could do to make it faster with 100 rows at a time. I will try with show/hide and keep you posted. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I see there is better performance. I am wondering (actually trying to understand technically) how can this happen by just hiding and showing. Thanks a lot for that. However I still see the same amount of file in our production/staging environment is faster then DEV. Note: All hardware configuration are same. And Also I see there is a problem in the height of frozen column. After all roes are edited, the height of the DIV (of frozen columns ) is about 20px more than te grid. I will try that in the demo example and update.

Comment: @SKumar: You are welcome! Do you read [the article](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/reflow) about **web browser reflow**? It describes *the reason* of slow performance in case of multiple changes on the page. Changes of hidden elements reduce a part of reflow job. If you use frozen columns in the grid then you should destroy frozen columns by call of `destroyFrozenColumns` before the loop, where you call `editRow`, and then recreate the frozen columns by new call of `setFrozenColumns`. It should improve the performance additionally.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the beautiful article and your answer. The performance is now acceptable after show/hide and destroy/set frozen columns. I just need one more help. In that same demo, you can see when a row is in inline edit mode, at that time working doesn't work. Could you please help me on that. Thanks again.

Comment: @SKumar: You are welcome! I post the answer in pauses in my main job or in my free time. Now I have to do other things. Switching from one subject to another one take time. It's better if you post new question where you explain the problem in details. I will read it later and try to help you. Currently I don't really understand your problem. Which test case you mean exactly If the row already in editing mode then start of `editRow` will be failed and the row will continue be editing like it was already. Please describe exactly the problem, which you need to solve, in the new question.

Comment: I really need your help in one more problem I am facing. I have posted that in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42662108/free-jqgrid-mutliselect-in-free-jqgrid-4-13-6

Comment: @SKumar: I have to do my main job too. Posting answers takes too many time. I'll read your question later. I recommend you in any way to use always the latest version of free jqGrid (it's 4.14.0 now). It would be good if you prepare JSFiddle demo, which reproduces the problems. You can get https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/yvbt6w54/1/ as the starting point, modify it, click update and to post me the URL of new demo, which reproduces your problem.

Comment: Thanks Oleg for looking into this. Yes, I understand that. sono hurries. I created a fiddle. But as I am not able to access jsfiddle at my workplace. I created the fiddle using my cell pone. So I musy have missed something, at this poit of time, it is not working, but I will look into this. Whenever you get a chance... https://jsfiddle.net/SudhirSahoo/h2k1ok2u/

Comment: @SKumar: Your jqfiddle don't display anything. It's better that I post you another **working** example of the usage Multiselect plugin: https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/h0mwtw8s/. The demo use new option `inFilterSeparator`, which you probably don't need.