# free-jqgrid: mutliselect in free-jqgrid 4.14.0

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, free-jqgrid

Not sure why the multi-select is not working when I select more then one value. I am using free-jqgrid 4.14.0 and multiselect js from erichynds. 
Also the multi-select is not coming as drop down. Am I missing any CSS or anything...

Any help please...

Created  fiddle, but since I can't access fiddle at my workplace, I used my cell phone, so it is not working now. I must have missed something. https://jsfiddle.net/SudhirSahoo/h2k1ok2u/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>SKumar - JQGrid</title>
    <meta name="author" content="SK Inspired from Oleg">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery-ui-multiselect/1.13.6/jquery.multiselect.css" />
    <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="jqGrid/css/ui.jqgrid.css">-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://rawgit.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/master/css/ui.jqgrid.css">
 
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/jquery-ui-multiselect/1.13.6/jquery.multiselect.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body { font-size: 75%; }
  #gridSearchResult {
   height: 460px;
  }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $.jgrid = $.jgrid || {};
        $.jgrid.no_legacy_api = true;
        $.jgrid.useJSON = true;
    </script>
    <!--<script src="http://rawgit.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/master/js/jquery.jqgrid.src.js"></script> -->
 <script src="https://rawgit.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/master/js/jquery.jqgrid.src.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="jqGrid/js/jquery.jqGrid.src.js"></script>-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
        /*global $ */
        /*jslint eqeq: true, browser: true, plusplus: true */
        $(function () {
            "use strict";
            var $grid = $("#list"),
                gridData,
                startTime,
                measureTime = false,
                timeInterval,
    myDefaultSearch = "cn",
                getColumnIndexByName = function (columnName) {
                    var cm = $(this).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'colModel'), i, l = cm.length;
                    for (i = 0; i < l; i += 1) {
                        if (cm[i].name === columnName) {
                            return i; // return the index
                        }
                    }
                    return -1;
                },
                modifySearchingFilter = function (separator) {
                    var i, l, rules, rule, parts, j, group, str, iCol, cmi, cm = this.p.colModel,
                        filters = $.parseJSON(this.p.postData.filters);
                    if (filters && typeof filters.rules !== 'undefined' && filters.rules.length > 0) {
                        rules = filters.rules;
                        for (i = 0; i < rules.length; i++) {
                            rule = rules[i];
                            iCol = getColumnIndexByName.call(this, rule.field);
                            cmi = cm[iCol];
                            if (iCol >= 0 && ((typeof (cmi.searchoptions) === "undefined" ||
                                  typeof (cmi.searchoptions.sopt) === "undefined")
                                 && rule.op === myDefaultSearch) ||
                                    (typeof (cmi.searchoptions) === "object" &&
                                        $.isArray(cmi.searchoptions.sopt) &&
                                        cmi.searchoptions.sopt[0] === rule.op)) {
                                // make modifications only for the 'contains' operation
                                parts = rule.data.split(separator);
                                if (parts.length > 1) {
                                    if (typeof filters.groups === 'undefined') {
                                        filters.groups = [];
                                    }
                                    group = {
                                        groupOp: 'OR',
                                        groups: [],
                                        rules: []
                                    };
                                    filters.groups.push(group);
                                    for (j = 0, l = parts.length; j < l; j++) {
                                        str = parts[j];
                                        if (str) {
                                            // skip empty '', which exist in case of two separaters of once
                                            group.rules.push({
                                                data: parts[j],
                                                op: rule.op,
                                                field: rule.field
                                            });
                                        }
                                    }
                                    rules.splice(i, 1);
                                    i--; // to skip i++
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        this.p.postData.filters = JSON.stringify(filters);
                    }
                },
                dataInitMultiselect = function (elem) {
                     setTimeout(function () {
                         var $elem = $(elem), id = elem.id,
                             inToolbar = typeof id === "string" && id.substr(0,3) === "gs_";
                             options = {
                                 selectedList: 2,
                                 height: "auto",
                                 checkAllText: "All",
                                 uncheckAllText: "None",
                                 noneSelectedText: "Any",
                                 open: function () {
                                     var $menu = $(".ui-multiselect-menu:visible");
                                     $menu.width("auto");
                                     return;
                                 }
                             };
                         if (inToolbar) {
                             options.minWidth = 'auto';
                         }
                         $elem.multiselect(options);
                         $elem.siblings('button.ui-multiselect').css({
                             width: inToolbar? "98%": "100%",
                             marginTop: "1px",
                             marginBottom: "1px",
                             paddingTop: "3px"
                         });
                     }, 50);
                 };


            var date = new Date(), t = Object.prototype.toString.call(date), t1 = String(date);

   $( "#search" ).click(function() {
    var statesAsString = getStates();
    startTime = new Date();
    $grid.jqGrid({
     datatype: 'json',
     url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/efhbt',
     mtype: 'GET',
       colNames: ['aa', 'bb', 'cc', 'dd', 'ee', 'ff', 'gg', 'hh', 'ii', 'Priority', 'Due Date', 'll', 'mm'],
     colModel: [
      { name: "aa", width: 200, label: "c01", frozen: true },
      { name: "bb", width: 200, label: "c02", frozen: true },
      { name: "cc", width: 100, label: "c03", frozen: true, search: true,
       stype:'select', 
        searchoptions: {
          sopt: ['eq','ne'],
          value: statesAsString,
          attr: {multiple: 'multiple', size: 3},
          dataInit: dataInitMultiselect
         }
      },
      { name: "dd", width: 100, label: "c04" },
      { name: "ee", width: 100, label: "c05" },
      { name: "ff", label: "c06" },
      { name: "gg", label: "c07", editable: true, stype: 'select', formatter: 'select',
       edittype: 'select', editoptions: {
        value: 'Select:Select;Y:Yes;N:No',
        multiple: false
       }
      },
      { name: "hh", label: "c08", editable: true, stype: 'select', formatter: 'select',
       edittype: 'select', editoptions: {
        value: 'Select:Select;Y:Yes;N:No',
        multiple: false
       }
      },
      { name: "ii", label: "c09", editable: true, stype: 'select', formatter: 'select',
       edittype: 'select', editoptions: {
        value: 'Select:Select;Y:Yes;N:No',
        multiple: false
       }
      },
      { name: "jj", label: "c10", width: 100, editable: true },
      { name: "kk", label: "c11", width: 100, editable: true, 
       formatter:'date', formatoptions: {newformat:'Y-m-d'}, datefmt: 'Y-m-d',
       editoptions: {
        size:20, 
        dataInit: function(el){ 
         $(el).datepicker({
          dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
          changeYear: true,
          changeMonth: true,
          showWeek: true,
          yearRange: '1999:+1',
          minDate: new Date()
         }); 
        }, 
        defaultValue: function(){ 
         var currentTime = new Date(); 
         var month = parseInt(currentTime.getMonth() + 1); 
         month = month <= 9 ? "0"+month : month; 
         var day = currentTime.getDate(); 
         day = day <= 9 ? "0"+day : day;
         var year = currentTime.getFullYear();
         return year+"-"+month + "-"+day; 
        },
        maxlength: 10
       },
       searchoptions: {
        sopt: ['eq'],
        dataInit: function (elem) {
         $(elem).datepicker({
          dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
          changeYear: true,
          changeMonth: true,                            
          showWeek: true,
          showButtonPanel: true,
          autoclose: false,
          currentText: "Clear",
          closeText: "Filter",
          yearRange: '1999:+1',
          onSelect: function( selectedDate, inst ) {
           $(this).focus();
           var target = $(selectedDate);
           var inst = this._getInst(target[0]);
           inst.inline = true;
           $.datepicker._selectDateOverload(selectedDate, inst);
           inst.inline = false;
           this._updateDatepicker(inst);
          }
         }).focus(function() {
          var thisCalendar = $(this);
          $('.ui-datepicker-close').click(function() {
           var selectedDate = $("#gs_kk").val();
           setTimeout(function () {
            $('#list')[0].triggerToolbar();
           }, 100);
           
          });
          
          $('.ui-datepicker-current').click(function() {
           var selectedDate = $("#gs_kk").val('');
          });
         });
        }
       }
      },
      { name: "ll", label: "c12", editable: true },
      { name: "mm", label: "c13", editable: true }
     ],
     cmTemplate: { width: 100, autoResizable: true },
     rowNum: 1000,
     records: 1000,
     rownumWidth: 40,
     rowList: [20, 100, 1000, 10000, "100000:All"],
     viewrecords: true,
     rownumbers: true,
     toppager: false,
     pager: false,
     shrinkToFit: false,
     multiselect: true,
     editurl: 'clientArray',
     loadonce: true,
     width: 800,
     height: 400,
     onSortCol: function () {
      startTime = new Date();
      measureTime = true;
     },
     /*onSelectRow: function (rowid) {
      var $self = $(this),
       savedRow = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam", "savedRow");
      if (savedRow.length > 0) {
       $self.jqGrid("restoreRow", savedRow[0].id);
      }
      $self.jqGrid("editRow", rowid);
     },*/
     loadComplete: function () {
      if (measureTime) {
       setTimeout(function () {
        //alert("Total loading time: " + timeInterval + "ms");
       }, 50);
       measureTime = false;
      }
     },
     autoencode: true,
     caption: "Shows the performance of resizing. Make double-click on the column resizer"
    }).jqGrid("filterToolbar", {
      beforeSearch: function () {
       startTime = new Date();
       measureTime = true;
       return false; // allow filtering
      }
    }).jqGrid("gridResize");
    $grid.jqGrid("setFrozenColumns");
   });
   
   
             timeInterval = new Date() - startTime;
             setTimeout(function () {
                // alert("Total time: " + timeInterval + "ms");
             }, 50);

   


    // On Click Of Button
   $( "#Change_Value" ).click(function() {
    var v = $("#name").val();
    var myGrid = $("#list");
    var selRowIds = myGrid.jqGrid("getGridParam", "selarrrow");
    //alert(selRowId.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < selRowIds.length; i++) {
     //rowData = myGrid.jqGrid("getLocalRow", selRowIds[i]);
     // one can uses the data here
     myGrid.jqGrid("editRow", selRowIds[i], true);
    }
   });
        });
  
  function getStates() {
   var statesAsString = '';
   $.ajax({
    type  : "GET",
    url   : "https://api.myjson.com/bins/xvjhl",
    ContentType : 'json',
    cache: false,
    async: false,
    success : function (data) {
     var len = data.length;
     for ( var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      if(!(data[i] == null || data[i].toUpperCase() == 'NULL'))
      {
       statesAsString += data[i] + ':' + data[i]+ ';';
      }
      } 
      statesAsString = statesAsString.slice(0, -1);    
    }
   })
   return statesAsString;
  }
    //]]>
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div style="border: 1px solid black; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px;">
  <TABLE width="100%">
   <TBODY>
    <TR>
     <TD align=left>
      Country: <input type="text" name="country" id="country" />
      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      State: <input type="text" name="state" id="state" />
      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <input type="button" name="search" id="search" value="Search" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
      
      <input type="button" name="reset" id="reset" value="Reset" />
     </TD>
     <TD align=right>
      <input type="button" name="Change_Value" id="Change_Value" value="Change Priority to High" /> 
     </TD>
    </TR>
   </TBODY>
  </TABLE>
 </div>
 
    <div id='gridSearchResult' style="margin-top: 10px;">
  <table id="list"></table>
    </div>
 <div style="border: 1px solid black; align: centre; margin-top: 10px; padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px;">
  <TABLE width="100%">
  <TBODY>
   <TR>
    <TD align=center>
     <input type="button" name="save" id="save" value="Save" />&nbsp;&nbsp;
     
     <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
    </TD>
         </TR>
  </TBODY>
 </TABLE>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You use very old code example, which I wrote before starting the project free jqGrid. Free jqGrid now support many features, which allows to simplify the code (and to make it working)

The demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/h0mwtw8s/ uses the following code:

```
var dataInitMultiselect = function(elem, searchOptions) {
    var $grid = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
        var $elem = $(elem),
            id = elem.id,
            inToolbar = searchOptions.mode === "filter",
            options = {
                selectedList: 2,
                height: "auto",
                checkAllText: "all",
                uncheckAllText: "no",
                noneSelectedText: "Any",
                open: function() {
                    var $menu = $(".ui-multiselect-menu:visible");
                    $menu.width("auto");
                    $menu.find(">ul").css("maxHeight", "200px");
                    return;
                }
            },
            $options = $elem.find("option");
        if (inToolbar) {
            options.minWidth = "auto";
        }
        $grid.triggerHandler("jqGridRefreshFilterValues");
        $elem.multiselect(options);
        $elem.siblings("button.ui-multiselect").css({
            width: "100%",
            margin: "1px 0",
            paddingTop: ".3em",
            paddingBottom: ".3em"
        });
    }, 50);
},
multiselectTemplate = {
    stype: "select", 
    searchoptions: {
        generateValue: true,
        //noFilterText: "Any",
        sopt: ["in"],
        attr: {
            multiple: "multiple",
            size: 4
        },
        dataInit: dataInitMultiselect
    }
};

$("#jqGridA").jqGrid({
    url: "...",
    datatype: "json",
    forceClientSorting: true,
    loadonce: true,
    colNames: ["Client", "Amount", "Tax", "Total", "Shipped via", "Notes"],
    colModel: [
        {name: "name", width: 85, editable: true,
            template: multiselectTemplate},
        {name: "amount", width: 75, template: "number"},
        {name: "tax", width: 52, template: "number"},
        {name: "total", width: 65, template: "number", editable:true},
        {name: "ship_via", width: 85, align: "center",
            template: multiselectTemplate},
        {name: "note", width: 100, sortable: false}
    ],
    rowNum: 10,
    loadui: "block",
    inFilterSeparator: ";",
    multiselect: true,
    multiPageSelection: true,
    loadComplete: function () {
        if (!this.ftoolbar) {
            // create filter toolbar if it isn't exist 
            $(this).jqGrid("filterToolbar", {
                defaultSearch: "cn",
                beforeClear: function() {
                    $(this.grid.hDiv)
                        .find(".ui-search-toolbar button.ui-multiselect")
                        .each(function() {
                        $(this).prev("select[multiple]").multiselect("refresh");
                    });
                }
            });
            $(this).triggerHandler("jqGridRefreshFilterValues");
            $(this.grid.hDiv)
                .find(".ui-search-toolbar button.ui-multiselect")
                .each(function() {
                $(this).prev("select[multiple]")
                    .multiselect("refresh");
            });        
        }
    },
    rowList: [10, 20, 30, 100],
    pager: true,
    pagerRightWidth: 135, // fix wrapping or right part of the pager
    viewrecords: true,
    sortable: true,
    shrinkToFit: false
}).jqGrid("navGrid", {edit: true, add: false, del: false, search: false},
{
  afterComplete: function(response, postdata) {
     $(this).jqGrid('resetSelection');
     var p = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam");
     p.selarrrow = [];
     beforeProcessingHandler.call(this, p.data);
  }
});
```

Comment: Can't we set value of multi-select drop down like we were doing earlier. For example my multi-select drop down values comes from another service. the earlier approach was : searchoptions: {
          sopt: ['eq','ne'],
          value: scorecardAsString,
          attr: {multiple: 'multiple', size: 3},
          dataInit: dataInitMultiselect
         }

Comment: Thanks Oleg, I see it is not easy to migrate from an older version of JQGrid to latest version. After making this change, I am now facing a lot of  issues.

Comment: @SKumar: Sorry, but you used version **4.3**, which is more as 5 years old. You have to migrate to more recent version many years ago. You have to do now the job, which you skipped last years. I recommend you to migrate to the new version (or to test for some compatibility problems) directly after publishing the next version. For example, both Chrome and Firefox supports only the latest and the previous version. Chrome publish new version every 1.5 months. Thus you *have to* organize migration to the next version of Chrome in 1-3 months. 5 years in unacceptable for the web development.

Comment: I already upgraded to 4.13. Now after I make this change, the frozen columns are not working. Frozen header is working, but not the body. Even after upgrading to 4.14, the frozen columns are working. But when I change the code to make the multi-select work, at that time, all problems come...

Comment: @SKumar: The version 4.13 was published more as year ago. After that I published **6** next version from 4.13.1 till 4.13.6. "in" operation is supported by free jqGrid since a long time (see [the issue](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/issues/252) published between 4.13.3 and 4.13.4 version). I'm not sure what is your question now. I can't do migration of your program for you.

Comment: I am so sorry, I apologize if I said something. I never mean to say JQGrid is bad. I like it so much and I always suggest my friends to use this plugin. The only thing (because of my limited knowledge on this), it is taking long time. Now for some reason, I don't see the multi-select drop down. I understand that you need to complete code to help me. I wish I could. since I am not able to open jsfiddle, it is becoming difficult for me to explain the issue.

Comment: @SKumar: I could understand all your problems, but I have my main job and the projects, which I have to implement till a short time (the next important presentation is at 28 march and I have to implement a lot of thing till the day). I spend a lot of my time for free jqGrid, which I develop for free, and I try to help other people on the stackoverflow. My personal resources are still restricted. Sorry, but you should solve some problems yourself. You should debug the existing code, find out the reason and fix it. If you'll find a bug in free jqGrid: please report it.